# Split a single page in 2 vertical half XSL-FO

Tags: xsl-fo

I have one single page in my PDF, half of the page is occupied by an image. For the rest half of page I want to split it in 2 vertical halves, so that whatever I write should be split in 2 vertical half on same page.

Below is the code I am trying:-

```
<fo:block-container page-break-inside="auto">
                                <fo:block>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="FirstPage/Quote"/>
                                </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

Any suggestion how it can be achieved. I have also attached a sample image showing what I wish to achieve.[image: sample_image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by specifying that your region-body must have 2 columns:

```
<fo:region-body column-count="2" column-gap="5mm"
```

and the elements that should span both columns (e.g. the block that contains your image) get a span atribute:

```
<fo:block span="all">
```